# Implementing Simon's oracle for a 2:1 function

Tags: quantum-gate, simons-algorithm

I'm trying to implement Simon's oracle for a 2 to 1 function like described in the answer for the same question here: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/6587/22394
As I interpret the answer it works as follows:

1. For all qubits copy the qubit value from the input register with CX to the corresponding qubit in the output register.
2. For a 1 at position x in the secret apply a CX from the highest value qubit in the input register to the the x-th qubit in the output register.

But for the following given secret '01' (Big Endian Notation) it doesn't work:

Step 1:
[image: Circuit after step 1]

Step 2:
[image]

Given this secret:
[image]

f(0) and f(1) build a pair and f(2) and f(3) build another.
According to this blueprint the output of f(0) and f(1) should be equal.
But inserting 00 -> 00 and 01 -> 01.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to your question, but one quick and dirty way of implementing the oracle would be using the qiskit [Truth Table Oracle](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stable/0.19/stubs/qiskit.aqua.components.oracles.TruthTableOracle.html). You just exhaustively specify inputs and outputs in a table and in the end you get a circuit which represents an oracle.

The problem with this approach is that your table grows exponentially with the number of qubits. On the other hand, you might try generating a small oracle (say for four qubits) and then examine the circuit for getting a clue about what gates were used.

The better way is trying to understand what DaftWullie described in the linked post, but I can't help with that.

Answer (score 0):

> You could do something like:
>
> 1. assume the most significant bit of  is 1.
> 2. write a function that says "if the most significant bit of  is 0, return . if the most significant bit of  is 1, return ⊕.

Your problem is Your most significant bit is a 0 not a 1.