# How to come up with Simon's Algorithm circuit for this 3 qubit system? (given truth table & s)

Tags: circuit-construction, quantum-circuit, simons-algorithm

I have this truth table, knowing that the S = 110. However, how do I come up with a circuit by recognizing the pattern? It has taken me hours but my 2 brain cells don't seem to get it...

I know there must be an intuitive guide to finding a pattern when implementing in circuits, but what is it? Is there a general rule of thumb for solving this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not saying this is a *good* way of doing it, but if you're completely stumped, there is always a fallback: use a multi-controlled-not. For example, if you use controlled-controlled-controlled-not, you can choose which of the 3 target bits to set to 1 (the second) if all three input bits are 1. Then, you flip the third input bit and apply another controlled-controlled-controlled-not. This applies an X if the original input as 110, so we do two of those, one targetting the first qubit, and one targetting the third. And so on...

(There are much better ways in this particular case. For instance, compare the xor of the 3 input bits with your intended first output bit. Also, compare your third input bit and the second output bit.)

Comment: You might also find some previous answers, such as this one: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/6587/1837 helpful.